# RStudio Git - The Directory Name is Invalid

Tags: r, git, bitbucket, rstudio

I have numerous local repos on my laptop that are linked to remotes on bitbucket, and git commands (inc. commit and push/pull) have been working in RStudio previously, but today all repos stopped working. They show the error "RStudio, directory name is invalid".

I am using W10, RStudio 1.1.463, git version 2.19.1.windows.1

I have tried the solutions to previous similar questions (repo paths do not contain non-ASCII char). I can use git with SourceTree, so I don't think it's an issue with my git version.

When I try to commit/pull/push changes it just shows "RStudio, directory name is invalid" and does not allow me to perform any git commands. Also, when I look at the git viewer in RStudio, it is just blank/white, whereas it would usually allow me to stage files etc.

**EDIT**

In an attempt to try and fix the issue, I uninstalled and reinstalled git. Whilst git works perfectly well with SourceTree and in the command line, RStudio is not able to find it i.e. in creating a VCS project it returns "Git was not detected on the system path". However, I have placed `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\` in the system path via environment variables. I have also set the git executable path in RStudio's global options as `C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe`. I even followed the steps here:

https://github.com/jennybc/happy-git-with-r/issues/67

The only difference was that for the critical change, instead of showing "**Use git from the windows command prompt**", it reads "**Git from the command line and also from 3rd-party software**", though I assume this is due to a difference in git version rather than any material difference. Does anyone have any ideas about how to fix this, as it'd be great to get RStudio finding git again?

Comment: What happens if you open a terminal pane and run `git status`? Is the working directory path correct?

Comment: And what is the directory name?

Comment: C:\Users\owner\Documents\Repos\rti\

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.
In Tools->Global Options...->Terminal, there were only 4 options: Command Prompt (32/64 bit) and Windows PowerShell (32/64 bit).
After installing [git for windows](https://gitforwindows.org) it had a 5th option "Git Bash", chose it, and it worked.

Comment: unfortunately I already have 'Git Bash' selected, but hopefully that helps others who have the same issue.